# IoT and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have to work on an IoT system. Basically sensors sending data to the cloud, and users being able to access the data belonging to them.
The amount of data can be pretty substantial so we need to ensure something that covers both security and heavy load.

The typology of data is pretty straightforward, basically a data and its value at a specified time.

The idea was to use DynamoDB for this, having a table with :

```
[id of sensor-array]
[id of sensor]
[type of measure]
[value of measure]
[date of measure]
```

The idea was for the IoT system to put directly (in python) data into the database.

Our questions are :

1. In terms of performance :

   - will DynamoDB be able to handle a lot of insertions on a daily basis (we may be talking about hundredth of thousands insertions per minute) ?
   - does querying the table by giving the id of the sensor array and a minimal date will ensure being able to retrieve the data in a efficient fashion?
2. In terms of security is it okay to proceed this way?

We used to use NoSQL like MongoDB, so we're finding hard to apply our notions on DynamoDB where the data seems to be arranged in a pretty simple fashion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> will DynamoDB be able to handle a lot of insertions on a daily basis (we may be talking about hundredth of thousands insertions per minute) ?

Yes, DynamoDB will sustain (and cost) all the write throughput you provision for the table. As your data is small, aggregating before writing in batches ([BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)) is probably more cost efficient than individual writes.

> does querying the table by giving the id of the sensor array and a minimal date will ensure being able to retrieve the data in a efficient fashion?

Yes, queries by hash (id) and range keys (date) would be very efficient. You may need secondary indexes for more complex queries though.

> In terms of security is it okay to proceed this way?

Although data is encrypted in transit and [client-side encryption is straightforward](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/client-side-encryption-for-amazon-dynamodb/), there is a lot uncovered here. For example, AWS IoT provides TLS mutual [authentication with certificates, IAM or Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/identity-in-iot.html), among other security features. AWS IoT can store data in DynamoDB using a [simple rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html).